# Python: No Output after opening file for reading

Tags: python, printing, stdout, error-logging

I have a python script which splits Icinga GUI commands and sends specific ones to satelite hosts.

The script does what it's written for, but I ran into 2 Problems:
First: I don't get debug output after the line 16 ("cgi_cmd = open(cgi_cmd_file, 'r')")
Second: The script is using upto 100% CPU, even as it should pause for 5 seconds everytime it fetches an empty line.

I could use some assistence here, thanks!

### Edit: solved

**My first problem ist related to the way named-pipes work. It can only be opened for reading if it was opened for writing first.**
**Second problem was the way I checked the line inside the loop, thanks to Peter Wood.**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import string, os, sys, re, spur, logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logging.debug('Imports done.')

# Define files and open
cgi_cmd_file = '/var/spool/icinga/cmd/cgi.cmd'
icinga_cmd_file = '/var/spool/icinga/cmd/icinga.cmd'
icinga_log_file = '/var/log/icinga/iscrdr_collector.log'
sat_log_file = '/var/log/icinga/iscrdr_satelite.log'

logging.debug('Files defined.')

cgi_cmd = open(cgi_cmd_file, 'r')
icinga_cmd = open(icinga_cmd_file, 'w')

logging.debug('Files opened.')

# Compile regex pattern for reschedule service and host checks
pattern = re.compile('SCHEDULE_.*_.*_CHECK.+?\d{10}')

logging.debug('Regex pattern compiled.')

# List of satelite hosts
satelite_hosts = [
    ['hostname','user','pw'],
    ['hostname','user','pw'],
    ['hostname','user','pw'],
]

logging.debug('Satelite hosts defined.')

#
# Code Area
#
def send_to_sat(message):
    command = "/bin/echo '" + string.strip(message) + "' > /var/spool/icinga/cmd/icinga.cmd"
    for i in satelite_hosts:
        shell = spur.SshShell(hostname=i[0], username=i[1], password=i[2])
        with shell:
            result = shell.run(["sh", "-c", command])
        logging.debug('Command send to' + i[0] + '.')
    with open(sat_log_file, 'a') as sat_log:
        sat_log.write(string.strip(message + str(result.return_code)) + "\n")

def send_to_icinga(message):
    with open(icinga_cmd_file, 'w') as icinga_cmd:
         icinga_cmd.write(string.strip(message) + "\n")
    with open(icinga_log_file, 'a') as icinga_log:
         icinga_log.write(string.strip(message) + "\n")
    logging.debug('Command send to Icinga.')

# Split reschedule commands from command stream and write them to file
while True:
    logging.debug('This is a loop run.')
    line = cgi_cmd.readline()
    if re.findall(r'SCHEDULE_.*_.*_CHECK.+?\d{10}', line):
        send_to_sat(line)
    elif line != '':
        send_to_icinga(line)
    else:
        logging.debug('No Command.')
        time.sleep(5)
        continue
```

Comment: I've heard `while True:` consumes a lot of CPU for some reason even if it's not actually doing anything.

Comment: @ForceBru It never sleeps as `line != ''` is always `True` ([except for last line of file](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects))